# What is the definition of this set of absolutely continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, lebesgue-integral

I know that

$$AC(a,b):=\left\{f \in C(a,b)|f(x) = f(c)+\int_c^x g(t) d \lambda(t),c \in (a,b), g \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(a,b)\right\}$$

$$AC[a,b]:=\left\{f \in C[a,b]|f(x) = f(c)+\int_a^x g(t) d \lambda(t), g \in L^1[a,b]\right\}.$$

Now I found the set $AC^1$, but without a definition what this set is. By looking at the context, I think it could be something like:

$$AC^1(a,b):=\left\{f \in C^1(a,b)|f(x) = f(c)+\int_c^x g(t) d \lambda(t),c \in (a,b), g \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(a,b)\right\}$$ or

$$AC^1[a,b]:=\left\{f \in C^1[a,b]|f(x) = f(c)+\int_a^x g(t) d \lambda(t), g \in L^1[a,b]\right\},$$
is this correct? Probably not, because we also want to have $f' \in L^1$ somehow. Therefore, I would be interested in an exaplanation what this set actually means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most natural way (to me) is to interpret the space $AC^1$ as the space of functions whose first derivative is in $AC$.

---

Remark: the class $AC$, as defined, is precisely the class of [absolutely continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) functions. Googling "AC1" together with "absolutely continuous" brought up, for example, [this paper](http://webs.uvigo.es/angelcid/Archivos/Papers/CC_JLMS_12.pdf) in which $AC^{1}$ notation is explained consistently with my answer: the space of functions with absolutely continuous first derivative.